# How to search/filter in react-table, if the accessor was the function

Tags: reactjs, react-table

In React-table, I have an `accessor` as the function. I am using `useFilter` to filter out the data, but it always returns an empty array.

Example Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-surf-78uz4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood what the `accessor` is supposed to do. You are returning a React Element/JSX, and according to the [docs](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable#column-options),

> The data returned by an accessor should be primitive and sortable.

To render the first cell as a link, change the `accessor` to "firstName", and modify the `tr` inside your `tbody` like this:

```
<tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
  {row.cells.map((cell, i) => {
    const renderedCell = cell.render("Cell");
    return (
      <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
        {i ? renderedCell : <a href="#">{renderedCell}</a>}
      </td>
    );
  })}
</tr>
```